# Spreading static files over hostnames

Tags: performance, http, dns, pagespeed

As part of my routine scan through things like PageSpeed Insights, I decided to put my images on separate hosts to improve parallel downloads. Images are now served from a subdomain like this:

> http://n26eh5.i.example.com/img/something.png

Where that `n36eh5` is the file's modification time, fantastic for cacheing since it will change immediately when the file does, automatically. Two birds with one stone, right?

Sure enough, I ended up scoring full points on the parallel downloads front.

Today I ran a test on another site. It's now telling me that I have too many DNS lookups.

Now... I have `*.i.example.com` set up as a wildcard vhost, but is that DNS lookup going to be an issue? With DNS cacheing, is it even a problem? After all, it will only be fetching that image the first time it gets requested, loading it from cache every time afterwards.

Should I look for a balance, or continue using the wildcard subdomain as I am now?

Comment: What test did you run? How did you get the error? Can you give some more details on the components involved except that you are using PageSpeed Insights?

Answer (score 0):

This question is mentioned in the talk Re-evaluating Front-end Performance Best Practices by Ben Vinegar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfDM4M6MC8E

the takeaway from that is it is not a good idea to use more than 2 hostnames in this way, my opinion from the talk it isn't really worthwhile doing it at all as there are most likely other things to improve performance anyway and, if you will probably have to do extra coding to make this work and we should try to code as little as possible to reach a solution.

He also said he probably should have answered the question and felt bad for not doing so.